# python ghostscript: RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)

Tags: python, macos, ghostscript

When trying to run hello-world example

```
import sys
import ghostscript

args = [
    "ps2pdf", # actual value doesn't matter
    "-dNOPAUSE", "-dBATCH", "-dSAFER",
    "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite",
    "-sOutputFile=" + sys.argv[1],
    "-c", ".setpdfwrite",
    "-f",  sys.argv[2]
    ]

ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

getting error:

```
 File "/Users/ddd/sss/ddd/eee.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ghostscript
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/ghostscript/_gsprint.py", line 290, in <module>
RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)
```

what is this libgs library and how can I get it?

btw I'm on mac

Answer (score 9):

For newer user who are using M1 mac, ghostscript might show a missing libgs file error and the file would be unavailable at `usr/local/lib`

The issue can be resolved by following these steps, in the same order:

- `brew install ghostscript`
- `conda install ghostscript`, which installs the arm_64 based library from conda-forge
- If conda throws a channel error try using `conda install -c conda-forge ghostscript`
- `pip install ghostscript`

Note:

1. The libgs.dylib file can be found in the home brew installation of ghostscript
2. Changing the address in `_gsprint.py` will throw an error as the brew installed version will be arm_64 based and the pip installed version will be OS_X86 based
3. Python doesn't recognise ghostscript module from conda install unless pip install is run, so that is an essential step

Answer (score 4):

Ok, if you're on mac M1 and using `python 3.9` that trick from the mentioned Github issue won't work probably. I did a few times what @Prajual suggested but didn't work either. [This](https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/issues/282#issuecomment-1023243604) helps.

1. First,

```
brew install ghostscript
```

2. Check out in brew lib what your version is. there should be a directory named like `9.56.1_1`

```
ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ghostscript/
```

3. Then copy that dylib file to where pip can access at `/usr/local/lib/` -- needs sudo privilege. **x.xx.xx would be your version from last command!**

```
sudo cp /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ghostscript/x.xx.xx/lib/libgs.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

You should now be able to `import ghostscript` with no problem.

Comment: Thanks - this worked well on the M2 chipset (without having to double install ghostscript with Conda). Rather than copy the library file, using a symlink worked just as well and allows for easier updates going forwards.
`sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ghostscript/10.0.0/lib/libgs.dylib /usr/local/lib/libgs.dylib`

Answer (score 2):

For me it was simply that I had installed the python parts:

```
pip install ghostscript
```

But not the C parts:

```
brew install ghostscript
```

Perhaps these DMGs work also - but I didn't go this route:
http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [**Ghostscript's official download site**](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/) as well as at [**their documentation**](http://www.ghostscript.com/Documentation.html).

If this doesn't get you started you could also ask the GS developers directly in their online chat channel named *#ghostscript* on IRC server *irc.freenode.net*. They are a very friendly and helpful bunch of people.

Answer (score 1):

To solve it, you need to modify ghostscript modules path in site-packages.

in _gsprint.py modify into something like this:

`libgs = ctypes.util.find_library('/opt/local/lib/libgs')`

which locates your libgs file.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac user find the version of the `libgs.x.xx.dylib` in your `/usr/local/lib/` directory.

Then run this command,

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libgs.x.xx.dylib /usr/local/lib/libgs.so

echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Replace `.zshrc` with your shell script type.

[replace x.xx with the version in your directory]

Comment: Mac  users can also try replacing the line
 
   `libgs = ctypes.util.find_library("gs")`
  
with 

    `import distutils.spawn`
    `libgs = distutils.spawn.find_executable("gs")`



      Link - https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/issues/282#issuecomment-604465648

Answer (score 0):

For other users on Mac that have tried @PrajualPillai's answer and it still didn't work, I'm posting @ArpanKushwaha's comment as an answer, because it was the only thing that worked for me.

For some reason, `ctypes.util.find_library("gs")` could not find my ghostscript install, so I had to replace it in

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ghostscript/_gsprint.py
```

At the top of the file, add

```
import distutils.spawn
```

and then replace

```
libgs = ctypes.util.find_library('gs')
```

with

```
libgs = distutils.spawn.find_executable("gs")
```

near the bottom of `_gsprint.py`.

If you also use camelot for pdf parsing you also need to replace `library = find_library("gs")` with `library = distutils.spawn.find_executable("gs")` in your `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/camelot/backends/ghostscript_backend.py`  file.