# RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)

Tags: python, runtime-error, png, ghostscript, eps

The problem I'm facing is the same as this one, but I'm on Windows. And using vs code. I've been trying to convert a postscript `.eps` file to an image `.png`. (Using pillow and turtle). That returned path to gs not found error. I installed ghost script, installed it's python version. but it shows error when i try to import it.

[python ghostscript: RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848903/python-ghostscript-runtimeerror-can-not-find-ghostscript-library-libgs)

Please help me resolve this, or find an alternate to convert the `*.EPS` to `*.PNG`. Appreciate your help, and I'm sorry if this makes no sense, kinda new to coding.

Comment: There is no Ghostscript library called libgs on Windows. On Windows the dynamic library is gsdll(32/64).dll. Of course, if you are running Cygwin or WSL you could be running a Linux application which might be looking for libgs.so, but in that case you'll need to install the Linux version of Ghostscript. Note that you can render an EPS to PNG on the command line just using Ghostscript itself, on either OS, which might be simpler.